# How to commit a ghost transaction in Postgresql 9.3?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a sample dataset restored from my customer's backup.
For some tables, the select count(*) returns a number, but the select * returns nothing.
I already rebuilt all indexes.
I suspect that these tables were loaded with an ETL process, using a transaction that was not committed, and all came to me with the backup.
How can I commit pending transactions, if any, in his case ?

Thanks.
Fred

Comment: If the transaction was not committed, `select count(*)` wouldn't return the correct number. How and where are you running that `select *`. If `count(*)` returns a number greater than zero, `select *` **will** return that number of rows

Comment: Furthermore, if there's an uncommitted tx, you can see it in `pg_stat_activity` or (if it's a prepared xact) `pg_prepared_xacts`. No need to guess.

Comment: Well, pg_prepared_xacts is empty.

Comment: Well, pg_prepared_xacts is empty. OK, not transactions. Actually, I test with Squirrel SQL, which gives this result. In the table properties, the Row Count returns 351, but the Content does not appear. It's the same for a few tables, not all. And this does not happen on the original database ...

Answer (score 0):

The source of the issue was the name of one colunm of the table: PCF_index

psql generated "PCF_index" when exporting the schema. This caused trouble to Squirrel when trying to read it.

After the column is renamed pcf_index, the issue was solved.

Comment: That sounds like a serious bug in Squirrel